# Aligning components in Box

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, boxlayout

*edit: if you downvote this question, you may leave a comment to explain why, that will be more constructive.*

I obtain this unexpected result...

[image]

... using this code:

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestAlignment extends JFrame {

    // Constructor
    public TestAlignment() {

        super("Test Alignment");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Components to show
        JLabel leftLabel = new JLabel("Left");
        JButton centerButton = new JButton("Middle");
        JLabel rightLabel = new JLabel("Right");

        // Add all to box
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box.add(leftLabel);
        box.add(centerButton);
        box.add(rightLabel);
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(180));

        // Align content in box
        leftLabel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        centerButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        rightLabel.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

        // Add box to frame, and show frame
        box.setOpaque(true);
        setContentPane(box);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create frame in EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {         
            @Override public void run() { new TestAlignment(); }
        });
    }
}
```

I understand now this works as expected for `JComponent.setAlignmentX()`: this method tells which sides of the components must be aligned (top label leftmost side aligned with button center and bottom label rightmost side).

I would like to understand how to have each label aligned as expected *intuitively* (left label on the left, right label on the right), labels touching the vertical edges of the Box?

(I know how to do with putting each label in a Box embedded, and using `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` to force it to the left or the right side, but seems to me too much for the simple purpose of alignment. I'm looking for something more simple)

Comment: If you had spent a moment reading the helpful tag pop-ups, you'd have realized this has nothing to do with what the [tag:box] tag was defined for..

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do this with a BoxLayout. Your example does show the intuitive code, which doesn't work as you would hope.

I would suggest you probably need to use a GridBagLayout. I think it supports the setAlignmentX(...) method the way you want to use it.

If not, then can use the [Relative Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). It is simple to use, like the BoxLayout and does support the alignment you want when you use:

```
setAlignment( RelativeLayout.COMPONENT );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BoxLyout:

```
        // Components to show
    // Left
    JLabel leftLabel = new JLabel("Left");
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    leftPanel.add(leftLabel);
    leftPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    // Center
    JButton centerButton = new JButton("Middle");

    // Right
    JLabel rightLabel = new JLabel("Right");
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    rightPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    rightPanel.add(rightLabel);

    // Add all to box
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.add(leftPanel);
    box.add(centerButton);
    box.add(rightPanel);
    box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(180));

    // Align content in box
    // leftLabel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    centerButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    // rightLabel.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```

[image]

Comment: I already knew this was possible using glue. As stated I'm looking for something more simple, if it exists. Anyway thanks for the answer Chen.